# How to use find in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
​<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>
            <div title="now">
                <div id="here">here</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>vvvv</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>vvvv</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div title="now">vvvv</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div  title="now">vvvv</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I am in `#here`. I would like add class from this place all div with `title="now"`. I want use find or others, but i can't set this as `$('div[title=now]')`.

```
$(#here).parent().parent().find(????).addClass('new');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "from this place"?

Comment: FYI: you have to wrap `#here` in quotes; either `$('#here')` or `$("#here")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#here").closest("tr").find("div[title=now]").addClass('new')
```

I've used `closest` here to find the first parent which is a `tr`, this is a little nicer than calling `parent` twice. The `find` is just as you wrote.

It's not particularly clear whether you want all three things with title=now selected or not, but you should be able to work it out from this!

Should do the job. Here's a fiddle showing what's going on. http://jsfiddle.net/MurwG/3/

(By the way, closest is quicker than parents as demonstrated here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/8)

Comment: His original code traversed up only to `td`. To be fair I can't tell what the OP exactly wants to select, though.

Comment: Cool, I've not come across the parents() method before!

Comment: Nah, the question isn't really clear is it! Hopefully this should help him out though.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#here").closest("td").find("div[title=now]").addClass('new')
```

I'm not sure whether you want to select all divs in the cell, or all in the row - then use `.closest("tr")`.

Answer (score 0):

$("#here").parent().parent().parent().find("div[title=now]").addClass("new");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

http://jsfiddle.net/2xAVn/